# Change Xpages View Selection Formula

Tags: combobox, xpages

I jave 2 combobox. and a view(viewPanel). I need to change viewSelection formula with the value from Combobox1 and Combobox2. 
Whan I choose from a value from combobox the view should be changed according to Value at combobox...

is there any example for how to do this?
Regards
Cumhur

Comment: You most likely don't want to change the underlying view. You can for instance filter a categorized view based on the contents from the combobox. Please clarify what the view looks like and how you want to change it.

Comment: Per is correct. If you change the underlying view, you need to rebuild the index and wait for that to be done before you can display it. And the view is a single view for all users, so changing the underlying view will affect anyone else who is on that page.